# Are STL vectors pass by reference/address?

Tags: c++, recursion, stl

I was solving a recursion problem. While solving, I got stuck in a position where I am unable to figure this out:

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

vector<int> Search(int arr[],int in, int n, int t, vector<int> &v){//v passed as ref.
    if(in == n){
        return v;
    }
    if(arr[in] == t){
        v.push_back(in);
    }
    return Search(arr, in+1, n, t, v);
}

int main(){
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 7, 4, 9, 4};
    vector<int> v;
    v = Search(arr, 0, 10, 4, v);
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
        cout << v.at(i) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In this code, I had passed the `v` as reference, but when I tried passing it without a reference then interestingly both of the codes worked.

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

vector<int> Search(int arr[], int in, int n, int t, vector<int> v){
    if(in == n){
        return v;
    }
    if(arr[in] == t){
        v.push_back(in);
    }
    return Search(arr, in+1, n, t, v);
}

int main(){
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 7, 4, 9, 4};
    vector<int> v;
    v = Search(arr, 0, 10, 4, v);
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
        cout << v.at(i) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can you explain why this happens?

Comment: *can you explain why this happen?* -- You mean the logic of your code?  Use a debugger  -- the logic isn't affected whether it is passed by value or by reference.  This has nothing to do with the difference between reference or value, it's just that regardless, your logic wasn't affected either way.   That is not the case if this were another problem, or you implemented your solution differently where reference/value would make a difference.  Also, `vector<int> Search` -- that plays a role.

Comment: because you are using the returned vector

Comment: You return by value in both cases. But there are no types that are "passed by reference by default" or something like that. Values are passed by value unless you explicitly pass by reference.

Comment: Unrelated, but you really shouldn't use `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`. It's not standard C++ and not portable. Use `#include<vector>` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of passing by reference you are pushing into the same `vector` that you pass in.

However when you pass by value you are pushing into a *copy* of the `vector`. But then you are returning the `vector` which returns the local copy, then you are assigning that (eventually) to the `vector v` in `main`. That's what makes it look like the code does the same thing even though it does not.